# permutation for string doesnt work for array of ints

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, integer, permutation

So I have the working string perm code below

```
public static List<String> myperm( String s ){
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    mypermImpl("", s, l );
    return l;
}

public static void mypermImpl( String built, String other, List<String> l ){
    if (other.length() == 0 ){
        l.add( built );
    }
    for ( int i=0; i<other.length(); i++ ){
        String leftover = other.substring(0,i) + other.substring(i+1);
        mypermImpl(built+other.charAt(i), leftover, l );
    }
}
```

Calling with "123" will return

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

Problem is if I use that as a model to do the same operation on array of int, them I'm not sure why this doesn't work, thoughts?

```
public static List<List<Integer>> myperm( int [] array ){
    List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> other = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for ( int i : array ){
        other.add( i );
    }
    mypermImpl(new ArrayList<Integer>(), other, l );
    return l;
}

public static void mypermImpl( List<Integer> built, List<Integer> other, List<List<Integer>> l){

    if (other.size() == 0 ){
        l.add( new ArrayList(built) );
        built.clear();
    }

    for ( int i=0; i<other.size(); i++ ){
        List<Integer> leftOver = new ArrayList<Integer>(other);

        leftOver.remove(i);

        built.add(other.get(i));
        mypermImpl(built, leftOver, l）；

    }
}
```

Produces the following

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[2, 1]
```

Thoughts??

Thank you

Comment: can i send you the another solution or you want to find the mistake from your code?

Comment: In your integer implementation, you clear the `built` list if `other.size==0`. You don't do that in your string version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are clearing the `built` array when you met the base condition. Because Java pass the arrays as reference, your `built` array is empty when is trying to insert the 3 in the second iteration.

You should make a copy of your `built` array before passing it

```
mypermImpl(built+other.charAt(i), leftover, l );
```

to emulate the behavior of the line above which creates another string before passing it.

Comment: Thank you that was it. I thought I could reuse. final edits: public static void mypermImpl( List<Integer> built, List<Integer> other, List<List<Integer>> l){

        if (other.size() == 0 ){
            l.add( new ArrayList(built) );
        }

        for ( int i=0; i<other.size(); i++ ){
            List<Integer> leftOver = new ArrayList<Integer>(other);
            
            leftOver.remove(i);

            List<Integer> built2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(built);
            built2.add(other.get(i));
            mypermImpl(built2, leftOver, l);
        }
    }